# Excel - How do I match a minute in time series with specified minute to return max value from another column?

Tags: datetime, logging, excel-formula, max

I am trying to extract the max values of CO2ppm (column E) that were logged every second over 1 hour (column D) for a total of 60 minutes (rows ~3300). I have column D for time (in HH:MM:SS) and CO2ppm (numeric). I have 50 CO2 samples that I collected that correspond with a minute (e.g. I collected sample #1 at minute 20:54 in F2), but the data is logging every second within that minute, and I want the the highest CO2 ppm in that minute).

The =MAX(IF(D:D=A2,E:E)) works to return the max value CO2ppm when I use the target value as the date (A2) for the entire day of sampling, but it does not work when I try to match my target minute (F2, 20:54) with the column D (HH:MM:SS). I tried to convert this column to text using  =TEXT(D:D,"H:M") so that the target value will match the values of minute, excluding all of the seconds, but with no luck.

How can I match my minute (F2) with the range of rows that have that minute (20:54:xx, column D) to find the max value in column E?

Example data:

[image: exampleData_ fields: Date, Time(text), Time(HH:MM:SS), CO2ppm, TimeofSample, SampleID, MaxCo2_ppm]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: Yes! I realize I can also accomplish this by using the PivotTable and summarizing Max by minute... but this is not conducive to building a reusable spreadsheet for future data: to comment example

Comment: Copy and pasting my sheet is not helpful to share in this post, it doesnt format easily, and I don't know how to share the example of the data itself.

Comment: Just make up some sample data for a snippet of columns D and E. Or add a screenshot and someone can help you with editing it into your question

Comment: I added the link in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to add a helper column with the timestamp stripped of the second component.

However in case that is not an option, you could use a formula like the following, which strips out the seconds from the timestamps in column D:

```
=MAX(IF((D2:D5-SECOND(D2:D5)/86400)=F2,E2:E5))
```

[image]

Depending on your version of Excel, you may have to confirm the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! The number of rows for each minute in the D column unfortunately is not always 60, so I won't be able to edit it. When logging the data, you can pause and resume logging, so the time can go from 20:17:00 and then 20:19:17 (if someone had to take a bathroom break and get back to logging). I truncated all the HH:MM:SS to cut the seconds off to HH:MM:00 so that my target time and the timestamp matches up, but that didn't work. I don't understand why logical operations such as = will work for dates and other numbers, but not the times.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Did you try this solution?

Comment: Dates/times are just numbers, so logical operations will work as anticipated. You do have to be aware of *text-that-looks-like-dates* or *text-that-looks-like-times* - these won't behave as expected.